# storing e-signature from PDF in SQL database

Tags: sql, pdf, adobe, livecycle

is there a way to store e-signatures in SQL Databases?
I have designed a form in adobe LiveCycle designer and I store all the information in my SQL database. I use a signature field to add the signature to the pdf.

The e-signature is from a USB token and certificate installed on my computer.

My question is how to add a signature to this database?

I hope you will understand my problem. Thanks for your answers! V.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? store the certificate in the database?

Comment: Have you got any answer...

Answer (score 2):

Many databases offer a [BLOB (Binary Large OBject)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) or similar type that can be used to store arbitrary binary data alongside relational data.

That said, what format is the signature? Is it a file of a certain type, or is it merely contained in a larger document? What database are you using?

Without this additional information, the above is about as specific an answer as I can give.

Comment: the signature is in a form of certificate which is stored an token (special flash-drive like device). The user signs the document by clicking on the signature field and it is added from the token device (after typing the users token password). The database is mysql.